# Must remove battery and reinsert it to power on Acer laptop

Tags: laptop, drivers, battery, power

This thread is related to

superuser.com/questions/1280302/how-to-avoid-having-to-power-reset-my-laptop-each-time-i-use-it

the previous solution only improved my situation.  My laptop will now power on without a power reset. 
But if I leave it off overnight, I have to remove the battery and then put it back in in order to power on.

It will also power on using A/C without a power reset and without removing the battery.

I am thinking that this is a driver related issue.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the two (windows 10) battery drivers and that resulted in the current improvement.  I have purchased two new batteries and they both behave the same.

Can someone help me determine how to check battery and driver compatibility?

Comment: Have you checked if Acer have any Bios level updates and if they have , installed them?

Comment: I checked the Acer site and it shows 3 bios updates for the E5 471G laptop.  Each briefly mentions what is updated but none mentions "power".  I am reluctant to choose one without knowing the consequences.  They show a warning in big red letters about updating the BIOS and how it can harm the laptop.  I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: NEW INFORMATION:  On a full charge it powers up/down with no problems.  I can do this over & over. After 10 hours if the laptop is off, I must remove the battery and insert it for it to turn on and off again.

Also, when I fully charge the battery and I leave it on A/C power with the battery in and the laptop turned off, the power shuts off (LED goes off) after about 4 hours and I have to remove/insert the battery again. As long as the laptop is on, the power does not fail. If the battery is out and the A/C remains connected the power does not fail.

Has anyone heard of anything like this?